# Karaf Cellar: Issue installing Kar file -> Maven can not find artifact

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, karaf-maven-plugin, apache-karaf-feature

Currently, I have two cellar nodes, with the same configuration in the same group.

I configured maven in the node A with a local repository in my network, reachable for both nodes. For this, I edited "org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.localRepository" in the file "/karaf/etc/org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg".

Then I try to install a Kar file in the cluster through following command:

```
cluster:kar-install [group] [path_to_kar_file]
```

All the features and bundles are installed in noda A without problems. But node B has problems somehow finding the artifact:

```
CELLAR FEATURE: failed to add repository URL mvn:com.myproject/myproject-feature-cluster/3.5.0-SNAPSHOT/xml/features.
java.io.IOException: Error resolving artifact com.myproject:myproject-feature-cluster:xml:features:3.5.0-SNAPSHOT: 
    [Could not find artifact com.myproject:myproject-feature-cluster:xml:features:3.5.0-SNAPSHOT in defaultlocal (file:////WL300348/Users/zunigal/eRVS/m2/repository/), Could not find artifact com.myproject:myproject-feature-cluster:xml:features:3.5.0-SNAPSHOT in sonatype.snapshots.deploy (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/), 
    Could not find artifact com.myproject:myproject-feature-cluster:xml:features:3.5.0-SNAPSHOT in ops4j.sonatype.snapshots.deploy (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ops4j-snapshots/), 
    Could not find artifact com.myproject:myproject-feature-cluster:xml:features:3.5.0-SNAPSHOT in spring-ebr-repository (http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/)
```

I also tried adding the localRepository in the list of org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories but nothing changed.

Karaf Version: 4.1.5

Cellar Version: 4.1.3

Answer (score 0):

you can use Apache Karaf Cave on Node A and create a repository which will be available via http as well. Afterwards, you can add new repository url in your Node B configuration. When you install a new bundle/feature then cellar will download from new repository on Node B.